# Area Routing Issues in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

It seems as if area routing is an issue for me. Here is my problem, I have an application with one area named Administration, I have a controller named DepartmentController. Now I need to create a route that will generate a link like http://www.example.com/Administration/Setup/Department.

Here is what I have done.

In the Route.Config file of the application I added a custom route like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DeptSetup",
            url: "Setup/Department/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Administration.Controllers" }
        );
```

With that I got The resource cannot be found.

I tried the AdmininstrationAreaRegistration like so:

```
  context.MapRoute(
                name: "DeptSetup",
                url: "Setup/Department/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "Administration.Controllers" }
            );
```

All didnt work. Pls point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the area part in the route URL template. Using `AdmininstrationAreaRegistration` is a right way as areas should be responsible for registering their own routes, but the route itself should look like:

```
url: "Administration/Setup/Department/{action}/{id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use **Area registration** (`AdmininstrationAreaRegistration`) class and should add **Administrator** (area name) to your `url` template:

```
context.MapRoute(
            name: "DeptSetup",
            url: "Administrator/Setup/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Department", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```